# Why this inequality is true?

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality

Why this following two inequalities are true? Where $c$ is a constant.

$P(X_n+Y_n\le x) \ge P(X_n\le x-c-\epsilon) -P(Y_n>c+\epsilon)$

$P(X_n+Y_n\le x) \le P(X_n\le x-c+\epsilon) +P(Y_n<c-\epsilon)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the events
$$
A=\{X_n\leq x-c-\epsilon\},\quad B=\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\},\quad C=\{Y_n>c+\epsilon\}.
$$
Suppose $A$ happens, then either $X_n+Y_n\leq x$ or $Y_n>x-X_n\geq x-(x-c-\epsilon)=c+\epsilon$. Thus, $A\implies B\cup C$ so
$$
\Pr(A)\leq\Pr(B\cup C)\leq\Pr(B)+\Pr(C)\implies\Pr(B)\geq\Pr(A)-\Pr(C).
$$
This is your first inequality.

Similarly, suppose $B$ happens, then either $X_n\leq x-c+\epsilon$ or
$$
X_n>x-c+\epsilon\implies x\geq X_n+Y_n>x-c+\epsilon+Y_n\implies Y_n<c-\epsilon.
$$
This implies
$$
\Pr(B)\leq\Pr[(X_n\leq x-c+\epsilon)\cup(Y_n<c-\epsilon)]\leq \Pr[X_n\leq x-c+\epsilon]+\Pr[Y_n<c-\epsilon].
$$